# Internet explorer started from WScript.exe will not on appear on top

Tags: wsh

We have recently added a new feature on our application to be able to shell out to another application. One of the commands is WScript.exe

In one part of the script, I wanted to be able to show a dialogue, so I create an instance of Internet Explorer, inject my html, and then wait for a hidden input element to be updated.

The windows scripting file (containing VBS) then calls

```
Dim explorer
Set explorer = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
explorer.StatusBar = 0
explorer.ToolBar = 0
explorer.Navigate "about:blank"
Dim document
Set document = explorer.Document
document.open
document.write html
document.close
explorer.Visible = True

Do
    WScript.Sleep 250
Loop Until document.getElementById("myValue") <> ""
```

This seems to work fine when I am debugging my main application. But when I run the application outside the debugger, the dialogue appears behind the application.

I believe that the problem is explained in the answer to this item:

[WScript.Shell AppActivate doesn't work every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381791/wscript-shell-appactivate-doesnt-work-every-time)

Essentially, this was working because I was developing this in debug mode. When out of debug mode, the instance of iexplore.exe was not directly started by wscript.exe - the iexplore.exe process is actually started by an instance of svchost.exe. This meant that the implicit SetForegroundWindow() does not work.

Can anyone suggest a way I can put this internet explorer windows in the foreground?
Or is there another way I can create a dialogue, without having to distribute any more components?

Comment: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate("Blank Page - Internet Explorer")` but replace the `Blank Page` text with a content of `<title>` tag of your `html`, if any…

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work.